# Returing Header Title in HeaderSection Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview

I can easily return the the title for header section like:

```
if(section == 1) {
}
```

and so on

I have this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if let UpperView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Head", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Head {
        let sectionTitle = ["Head0","Head1","Head2"]
        var mysection = 0
        for sectitile in sectionTitle
        {
            if(section == mysection)
            {

                UpperView.lhlHead.text = sectitile
                mysection += 1

            }

        }            
        return UpperView
    }
    return nil

}
```

I want to set Head1, Head2,Head3 in a label of header view.

It works fine when i use this:

```
if(section == 0) {
    UpperView.lhlHead.text = "Head0"
} else if(section == 1) {
    UpperView.lhlHead.text = "Head1"
} else if(section == 2) {
    UpperView.lhlHead.text = "Head2"
}
```

When is use array no strings are seen. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `mysection` is always set to 0, but it is compared to current section's number, which varies from 0 to number of sections in your table. So the check `section == mysection` will pass only for the first section's header and you will get title set only into first section's header.

Instead, this function gives you number of the section (`section: Int`) that is processed, and you have `sectionTitle` array which matches section number (array index) with section's title. So instead of:

```
if let UpperView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Head", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Head {
    let sectionTitle = ["Head0","Head1","Head2"]
    var mysection = 0
    for sectitile in sectionTitle
    {
        if(section == mysection)
        {

            UpperView.lhlHead.text = sectitile
            mysection += 1

        }

    }            
    return headerView
}
return nil
```

you can just use this:

```
if let UpperView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Head", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Head {
    let sectionTitle = ["Head0","Head1","Head2"]
    UpperView.lhlHead.text = sectionTitle[section]          
    return headerView
}
return nil
```

Also, do not capitalize variable name, so the right code is this:

```
if let upperView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Head", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Head {
    let sectionTitle = ["Head0","Head1","Head2"]
    upperView.lhlHead.text = sectionTitle[section]          
    return headerView
}
return nil
```